# Bootstrap Aggregation

Tags: bootstrap

This might be a simple question: I have 8 samples and say 100 independent variables for each sample. I would like to calculate a correlation matrix and more specifically use a bootstrapped estimate of the pairwise correlations among the independent variables. Is there any benefit to generating an Average of bootstrap estimates ?? Is this the right definition of "bagging" ... all I am interested at this point is generating the best estimate possible.
    Thanks for any pointers and discussion in this regard.

Comment: A correlation matrix is not the same as a set of pairwise correlations.  What is your precise goal?

Comment: I should rephrase .. a matrix of pairwise correlations.  The goal to get more precise estimates of pairwise correlations by using the bootstrapped estimator